# Genetic algorithm for 8 puzzle problem not working

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

```py
"""
    Simulate a genetic algorithm to solve 8 puzzle problem. Consider a pair of initial and final states. where the goal state is at minimal depth 10.

    Initial Population->Calculate Fitness->Select Parents->Crossover->Mutate->Repeat (until goal state is reached)

    initial_state = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8]

    final_state = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 0, 7]

""" 
# Functions for 8 Puzzle

def print_board(state):
    print("-------------")
    print(f"| {state[0]} | {state[1]} | {state[2]} |")
    print("-------------")
    print(f"| {state[3]} | {state[4]} | {state[5]} |")
    print("-------------")
    print(f"| {state[6]} | {state[7]} | {state[8]} |")
    print("-------------") 


def find_blank(state):
    return state.index(0)

def swap(state,index1,index2):
    temp=state[index1]
    state[index1]=state[index2]
    state[index2]=temp
    

def move_up(state):
    dup = state.copy()
    blank_index=find_blank(dup)
    if blank_index>2:
        new_blank_position = blank_index-3
        swap(dup,new_blank_position,blank_index)
    return dup

def move_down(state):
    dup = state.copy()
    blank_index=find_blank(dup)
    if blank_index<6:
        new_blank_position = blank_index+3
        swap(dup,new_blank_position,blank_index)
    return dup

def move_left(state):
    dup = state.copy()
    blank_index=find_blank(dup)
    if blank_index%3!=0:
        new_blank_position = blank_index-1
        swap(dup,new_blank_position,blank_index)
    return dup

def move_right(state):
    dup = state.copy()
    blank_index=find_blank(dup)
    if blank_index%3!=2:
        new_blank_position = blank_index+1
        swap(dup,new_blank_position,blank_index)
    return dup

def mhd(state,final_state):
    distance = 0
    for index in range(len(final_state)):
        current_val = state[index]
        if current_val!=0:
            goal_index = final_state.index(current_val)
            current_row = index/3
            current_col=  index%3
            goal_row = goal_index/3
            goal_col = goal_index%3
            distance+=abs(int(current_row-goal_row))+abs(int(current_col-goal_col))
    return distance



# Genetic Algo functions

import random

def calculate_fitness(state,goal_state):
    return mhd(state,goal_state)


def select_best_solutions(fitness_map):
    fitness_map = dict(sorted(fitness_map.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
    return list(fitness_map.keys())[:5]
    

def crossover(parents):
    parents = random.sample(parents,2)
    parent1 = parents[0]
    parent2 = parents[1]
    
    crossover_point = random.randint(0, len(parent1))
    child1 = parent1[:crossover_point] + parent2[crossover_point:]
    child2 = parent2[:crossover_point] + parent1[crossover_point:]
    return [child1,child2]

def mutate(children):
    mutated_children = []
    for child in children:
        child = list(child)
        child+=random.choice(['L','R','U','D'])
        mutated_children.append(''.join(child))
    return mutated_children

def run_genetic_algo():
    # generate initial population
    start_state=[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 6, 8, 0]
    goal_state=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]

    directions = ['L','R','U','D']
    initial_population = []

    for x in directions:
        for y in directions:
            initial_population.append(x+y)

    random.shuffle(initial_population)

    for generation in range(100000):

        initial_states = []
        for move in initial_population:
            temp_state = start_state.copy()
            for turn in move:
                if turn == 'L':
                    temp_state=move_left(temp_state)
                elif turn == 'R':
                    temp_state=move_right(temp_state)
                elif turn == 'U':
                    temp_state=move_up(temp_state)
                elif turn == 'D':
                    temp_state=move_down(temp_state)
            if goal_state == temp_state:
                print("Goal State Reached")
                print("Start State: ")
                print_board(start_state)
                print("Goal State: ")
                print_board(goal_state)
                return
            initial_states.append(temp_state)
        initial_states=list(filter(lambda x:x!=None,initial_states))

        # calculate fitness
        fitness_values=[]
        fitness_values = [calculate_fitness(state,goal_state) for state in initial_states]
        fitness_map = dict(zip(initial_population,fitness_values))

        print("Generation: ",generation)
        print("Initial Population: ",initial_population)


        # select parents
        parents = select_best_solutions(fitness_map)

        # crossover
        children = crossover(parents)


        mutated_children = mutate(children)

        # replace last 2 elements of initial_population with mutated_children
        initial_population[-2:]=mutated_children
        random.shuffle(initial_population)

    

run_genetic_algo()
```

I am trying to solve 8 puzzle problem using genetic algorithm, but it's not working. Here is my approach:

1. I have start state and end state.
2. I generate some random list of moves for it (LR,RL,UD,...etc)
3. Generate states corresponding to those moves
4. Find the parents (I do it using manhattan distance), the states with the list manhattan distance are selected).
5. For generating children I swap random moves from the parents, and add a new move on top of it (mutation).
6. And repeat until the goal state is not found.

Comment: Don't just say "not working.."  what is happening, what should happen. Any error, log ? 
read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By not working I mean: I am not able to reach to final state.

Comment: Did you try to minimize the problem and debug why it's not reaching the final state? Which function is the problem isolated to? If it hasn't been isolated, then there's more work to be done before asking. Please see [mcve] for help with that.